Can I get all items from multiple SharePoint lists using none-premium connector
I have a site content type named "Asset", and we are adding custom lists and add this content type to them. now using Power Automate I want to get all items from all the underlying custom lists (which have the Assets content type and that were modified in the last 24 hours ago)>> check if 2 columns are equal if not to update the 2 columns to be equal. so can I do this inside scheduled flow? can I benefit from SharePoint search  api to get items from multiple lists? the service account running the flow does not have premium license.

If you are willing to drop SharePoint search API, then non-premium plan would be:

create one child flow with all business logic.
then create separate trigger flows for each list/lib and call that child flow.

Literally do not do anything else - just trigger and one action "Run a Child Flow". In this case you will have centralized all logic and "actual" code in single (child) flow that process all items from all lists.
